# cant find correct font

Tags: css, fonts

This may not be an ordinary question you see here on this site but it's the best website to ask questions!

I have been searching for ages but I can't find the correct font!
[image]

The image you see above I took from a website that uses this font. I have been searching and I can't find the font that looks like the image above. If you recognize this font, please write in the chat what it's called or send a link to where I can find it! Thank you.

Sorry for bad spelling I'm from Sweden.

Comment: What is the website you got the font from?

Comment: http://8theme.com/demo/royal/?page_id=16411&et_styles=0-1-1-8-0-1

Answer (score 0):

It's a Font called "Railway Black", you can find, and download it here:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Raleway